# Nodejs Comparing two csv files and fetch the difference data by applying algorithm

Tags: node.js, algorithm, csv

I need to compare two csv file using nodejs by applying some algorithm.

Algorithm to compare two csv files and fetching the difference data(Like Entity Matching algorithms)

could anyone suggest some algorithms ?

Comment: If you're asking about an algorithm - node.js is not relevant. If you're asking about an off-site resource - this question is off-topic.

Comment: I am not asking about off-site resource or off-topic, i need to apply some algorithms to compare csv files and fetch the difference. I tried already with npm packages available in node js, now need to apply some algorithms

Comment: try this library https://github.com/kpdecker/jsdiff